# Unable to solve the error of TestNGContent Handler in Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

My XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="DUMMY" parallel="tests" thread-count="1">

<parameter name="RUN_USING_SG" value="N"/>
<test name="Verify LaunchApplication"/>


<parameter name="BROWSER_CODE" value="FF"/>
<parameter name="URL" value="http://demo.rtcamp.com/rtmedia/"/>
<parameter name="TITLE" value="rtMedia"/>
<parameter name="PLATFORM" value="WINDOWS"/>
<parameter name="VERSION" value="ANY"/>
<classes>
<class name="modules.LaunchApplication"/>
</classes>

</test>
</suite>  <!--Suite-->
```

My Error

```
org.testng.TestNGException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:341)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:88)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at  org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.xmlClasses(TestNGContentHandler.java:342)
at  org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.endElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:693)
at  com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:39)
at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:17)
at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:10)
at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:168)
at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:311)
... 3 more
```

I am getting above error when i am going to run my test script with testng.I am getting this error first time not sure what is it? when I run my test with junit it is working fine but not with testng.I have checked my xml file it is also correct.Any Help To get out from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to close a tag  which is already closed.

```
<test name="Verify LaunchApplication"/>
```

And

```
</test>
```

Comment: [TestNG] Running:
  D:\workspace3\shiv_project\TestScripts\LaunchApplication.xml


===============================================
DUMMY
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

Comment: No,one of the parameter is missing and I add the parameter and problem get solved.